# Does "true" in C always mean 1?

Tags: c, if-statement

Please consider these piece of C code:

```
if ((value & 1) == 1)
{

}
```

Assuming value equals 1, will `(value & 1)` return 1 or any unspecified non zero number?

Comment: What does the title have to do with your question? `&` is not a boolean operator; it doesn't return true/false.

Comment: I hope `value` is not a floating point number.

Comment: I am open to any better title suggestions. Anyways thank you for help.

Comment: `value & 1` can only be 0 or 1 and this has nothing to do with "true".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**§6.5.8 Relational operators**

> Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false.) The result has type int.

**§6.5.9 Equality operators**

> The == (equal to) and != (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational operators except for their lower precedence.) Each of the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type int. For any pair of operands, exactly one of the relations is true.

**§6.5.13 Logical AND operator**

> The && operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

**§6.5.14 Logical OR operator**

> The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

Comment: Does this answer the question in the title or the one in the code?

Comment: @RadLexus I'm assuming the OP confused `&` with `&&` in his code from the way he phrased his question (will the expression return 1 or some other non-zero value?).

Comment: Hi @GovindParmar, where did you extract this data from please?

Comment: @Rizzo this is from the C language standard; a Google search will lead you to it

Answer (score 6):

> Does “true” in C always mean 1?

No. Any expression that evaluates to a non-zero value is "true" in C. For example,

```
if (-1) {
}

if (5-10) {
}

if( "string literal") {
}
```

are all "true" and pass the condition.

In your specific example, the relational operator `==` yields 1 which is also "true"(the same holds for all other relational operators as noted by Govind).

---

If you are really asking about whether the bit-wise AND (`&`) yields 1 when `value` is 1, then yes, `value & 1` yields 1 (assuming `value` is an integer type -- `&` operator requires its operands to be integers).

In fact, you can probably try to understand the individual parts and (generally how the `&` and `==` operators behave) by using a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int value = 1;
  printf(" value & 1 = %d\n", value & 1);
  printf(" 2 & 1 = %d\n", 2 & 1);
  printf("((value & 1) == 1) = %d", (value & 1) == 1);
}
```

Comment: On your last line: the mention of `&` in both example code and wanted explanation has nothing to do with either the value '1' or 'true', because it is a *bitwise* operator, not a logical one.

Comment: @RadLexus Seems like a long shot to be really sure about what's exactly asked. The title and "true" strongly implies it's about the `if` statement itself. But the last line of the question, contradictorily, it's about the bitwise AND. I *tried* to explain both