# Specifying a range inside an if condition in C language

Tags: c, if-statement, range

I just want to know the difference between these C code segments. I used it in two different ways and final output was not same.

```
if(120<=units<160){
    
    total= total- total*(15.0/100);
    printf("Revenue : %.2f", total);
    
}


if(120<=units && units<160){
    
    total= total- total*(15.0/100);
    printf("Revenue : %.2f", total);
    
}
```

Can't we use "120<=units<160" to specify a range in C language?

Comment: No, you cannot do that.

Comment: Think through the results of the operators, and operator precedence/associativity.

Comment: Aside: `total= total- total*(15.0/100);` looks simpler as  `total *= 0.85;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't test ranges in this way. What's happening here is the operators are evaluated left-to-right as per [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

So this means: `(120 <= units) < 160`

The value of `120 <= units` will be 0 if it is false or [1 if it is true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41926288/1553090)

In other words, the full expression will always be true, because both 0 and 1 are less than 160.

Answer (score -1):

It's parsed as one of these two (I don't remember which):

- `(120 <= units) < 160`
- `120 <= (units < 160)`

In both cases, one comparison is done, yielding a "boolean" (`0` or `1`) which is then compared with the other number, typically leading to a "wrong" result (well, it's perfectly correct, just doesn't match your expectation)

Comment: Left to right for comparison operators. The only binary operators with right to left associativity are the assignment operators

Answer (score -1):

The question is similar to a post in C++. You can refer to the post in the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831148/19395482

By Matthieu M.:

> Consider the single statement: bool result = 18 < age < 30;
> We want to evaluate the right-hand expression: 18 < age < 30
>
> There are two operators in this expression, and since they are identical, they both have the same priority, in this case, they are thus evaluated from left to right, therefore the expression is equivalent to:

```
(18 < age) < 30
```

> So let's first examine the left-hand member: 18 < age, it yields a boolean which is either true or false, typically represented as an integral value respectively 1 or 0. Thus the expression can be summed up as:

```
{0,1} < 30
```

> which is always true.
>
> Therefore, should you use assert(18 < age < 30); it would never backfire.